# Convert ordinal to numbers

Tags: r, type-conversion, ordinal

Is there a built-in way to convert ordinal numbers to numeric vectors?

```r
ordinal <- c("First", "Third", "Second")
ordinal_to_numeric(ordinal)
#[1] 1 3 2

ordinal2 <- c("1st", "4th", "2nd")
ordinal_to_numeric(ordinal)
#[1] 1 4 2
```

One could indeed create a dictionary, but this could be cumbersome easily.

Comment: Take a look at the [english](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/english/index.html) package.

Comment: I know they have numeric to ordinal, but I'm not aware of ordinal to numeric.

Comment: Ah you're right - for some reason I remembered it as two-way.  Could always generate a dictionary and match back.  Not sure what range of ordinal numbers you have.

Comment: True, although I'm more trying to find a built-in way

Comment: `readr::parse_number()` will conveniently handle your second case, or `as.numeric(sub("\\D+$", "", ordinal2))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly built-in, but you can use Ritchie Sacramento's suggestion of the `english` package.  You first make a long string of the ordinal values in words.  Then you find the place of your words in these ordered list of ordinal values:

```r
library(english)
ordinal <- c("First", "Third", "Second")
o <- ordinal(1:1000)
match(tolower(ordinal), o)
#> [1] 1 3 2
```

The second, as Ritchie suggests, is less complicated.  I used a slightly different method, but ultimately it does the same thing.

```r
ordinal2 <- c("1st", "4th", "2nd")
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(ordinal2, "\\d+"))
#> [1] 1 4 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You could even put them together in a single function:

```r
ordinal_to_numeric <- function(x, max_ord=1000){
  if(any(grepl("\\d", x))){
    as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+"))
  }else{
    require(english, quietly = TRUE)
    o <- ordinal(seq(1,max_ord, by=1))
    match(tolower(x), o)
  }
}
ordinal <- c("First", "Third", "Second")
ordinal_to_numeric(ordinal)
#> [1] 1 3 2

ordinal2 <- c("1st", "4th", "2nd")
ordinal_to_numeric(ordinal2)
#> [1] 1 4 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is a great workaround indeed

Answer (score 3):

I’m late to the party and @DaveArmstrong’s solution is definitely simpler, but here’s a slightly more generic solution that first converts ordinals to cardinals, then passes these to `nombre::uncardinal()` for conversion to numeric. The `str_replace_all()` vector for ordinal -> cardinal conversion is based on [source code](https://github.com/rossellhayes/nombre/blob/e43bfe3dc69e4a9d832fcf90d9a56d773c127a92/R/ordinal.R) for `nombre::ordinal()`.

```
library(stringr)
library(nombre)

ordinal_to_numeric <- function(x) {
  w_word_stem <- function(x) {
    x |>
    str_to_lower() |>
    str_remove("st$|nd$|rd$|th$") |>
    str_replace_all(c(
      "fir$" = "one",
      "seco$" = "two",
      "thi$" = "three",
      "f$" = "ve",
      "eigh$" = "eight",
      "nin$" = "nine",
      "ie$" = "y"
    )) |>
    uncardinal()
  }
  w_num_stem <- function(x) {
    x |>
      str_extract("^-?\\d+") |>
      as.numeric()
  }
  out <- suppressWarnings(ifelse(
    str_starts(x, "-?\\d"), 
    w_num_stem(x),
    w_word_stem(x)
  ))
  if (any(is.na(out) & !is.na(x))) {
    warning("Conversion failed for some inputs")
  }
  out
}

ordinal <- c("First", "Third", "Second", "Five Hundred Thirty Eighth", "Negative Twenty-Third")
ordinal_to_numeric(ordinal)
# 1   3   2 538 -23

ordinal2 <- c("1st", "4th", "2nd", "538th", "-23rd")
ordinal_to_numeric(ordinal2)
# 1   4   2 538 -23
```