Convert ordinal word string to ordinal number string?
Suppose I have a vector containing ordinal number words as strings in R:
ordinal_words<-c("FIRST COMPANY", "BAKERY FIFTH AVENUE", "WEST FORTIETH WAY")

I would like the ordinal number word strings like "FIRST" to be converted to ordinal number strings like "1ST". My ideal output is:
ordinal_words<-c("1ST COMPANY", "BAKERY 5TH AVENUE", "WEST 40TH WAY")

Is there any way to do this in R? I would greatly appreciate an explanation of how to do this.
I am NOT trying to convert ordinal strings to to numeric vectors. I want to convert a string like "FIRST COMPANY" to a string like"1ST COMPANY". There is another post linked in a comment that is a bit similar, but I am not trying to do the same thing that question is doing. This other post is linked below:
stackoverflow.com/questions/75082003/convert-ordinal-to-numbers

check the numberize package

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082003/convert-ordinal-to-numbers

@BrianSyzdek  Hi I have a different question than the one you are linking. They are trying to convert ordinal strings to numeric vectors; I am NOT trying to convert ordinal strings to to numeric vectors. I want to convert a string like "FIRST COMPANY" to "1ST COMPANY"

You can use stringr::string_replace_all(ordinal_words, pattern), where pattern is a named vector of ordinal strings created using ord_num <- scales::ordinal(1:100) with the names coming from ord_str <- english::ordinal(1:100)). Note that these functions give different results, but can be used together to create the required named vector: pattern <- setNames(ord_num, toupper(ord_str)).

@IRTFM This question should be re-opened

All you need to do is replace the characters in the section of zephryl's solution that uses the str_replace_all function with the numeral characters that are appropriate.``"fir$" = "1", "seco$" = "2", "thi$" = "3", "fif$" = "5", "eigh$" = "8", "nin$" = "9". You might need to add some fo higher order items like "hundred"="100" and if all your characters are caps, you might need to use different equivalencies, but that's not our responsibility.
